# Simple auth addon seems to not be reading env config

Tags: ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am following the example [here](https://github.com/givanse/ember-cli-simple-auth-devise/blob/master/my-frontend/config/environment.js#L24), and I have this in my `config/environment.js` file:

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise',
  routeAfterAuthentication: 'landing-pages'
};
```

However, after my app authenticates it tries to go to the `index` route. I confirmed the configuration variable used had `index` as the `routeAfterAuthentication` property by adding a breakpoint in the `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` method of the library.

I tried `import`ing the configuration in the `environment.js` file ES6-style, but that doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Simple Auth actually still relies on the `window.ENV` configuration variable, so you'll need to add it to your configuration. Do it like this:

```
  window.MyAppENV = {{ENV}};
+ window.ENV = window.MyAppENV;
  window.EmberENV = window.MyAppENV.EmberENV;
```

Comment: I had a similar situation with ember-cli and the simple-auth test library, added this to my tests/index.html and it now picks up the environment config as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When used with the [Ember CLI Simple Auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth) addon, Ember Simple Auth uses the `ENV['simple-auth']` configuration set in `config/environment.js` like below:

...

```
  var ENV = {
    ...
  };

  ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    routeAfterAuthentication: 'some.route.name.you.choose'
  };

  ...
```